# Best way to sort rows of a matrix by specific element in C

Tags: c, sorting

I'm reading a file which contains fixed columns and rows that I will represent as a matrix using a double pointer (allocating memory) to represent that data.
I've already saved the data in the matrix, but now I want to sort all the rows by a specific int number that's in the position A[i][n] (i for rows and n for the specific column) so this element will be the element that will define the order of the rows in the matrix.

Which sort algorithm should I use?
I was thinking in Merge Sort but I'm currently allocating a lot of memory to include auxiliary arrays for the Merge function in Merge Sort and extra steps to copy all rows into the aux. matrix.

Now I'm thinking in Insertion Sort, which will be O(n*n) but I think it's better against Merge Sort because I won't be using dynamic memory allocation for auxiliary matrix (arrays) for the merge function in M. Sort.

Any ideas?

Comment: I really think you're focusing on the wrong thing. Get your matrix sorting with `qsort`, then you can fiddle with the algorithm if you like. And how many rows are there in your array? If there's < 25 you might just as well use bubble sort in order to get it all working. But choice of algorithm is the wrong thing to be concerned about at this point IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different algorithms give different results depending on the size and the initial (unsorted) state of the array; number of rows in your case, as you'll be sorting on rows (for a specific column). In general, **quick sort** suits when sorting integers.

```
// values before sort

// new array vecCol created by copying the column vector A[i][n]
vecCol = {13, 15, 12, 10, 14, 11};

// new vector to store the corresponding row positions at initial state
vecPos = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

When sorting the column vector `vecCol`, you need to switch the corresponding position vector `vecPos` for each switch operation done on `vecCol`...

```
// after sort
// you're done with this vecCol, you can free the memory allocated for this array.
vecCol = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// final state of vecPos, showing which row goes where...
// 3rd row goes to zero, 5th goes to 1st, 2nd stays in place, etc...
vecPos = {3, 5, 2, 0, 4, 1};
```

Then, switch the row pointers of the matrix `A` according to the final `vecPos`.

```
for (int row = 0; row < no_of_rows; row++) {
    if (row != vecPos[row]) {
        // if matrix values are ints, define "tmp" pointer as int*
        // if matrix values are double, define "tmp" pointer as double*, etc...
        int *tmp = A[row];
        A[row] = A[vecPos[row]];
        A[vecPos[row]] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i think this could be the way i'd do the sorting.

Comment: While it is fine to understand the different sorting algorithms, in C `qsort` is the tool to use. It will be *Orders Of Magnitude* faster and much more well-tested than anything you come up with on the fly. Well worth the time to learn how to write the simple compare function to make it work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I didn't know the existence of that function! I'll definitely use it on my future codes. But I was trying to code the sorting algorithm by myself to take its Big O for my project. Thank you:)